# MVC 4 How to call Upload function In Extisting Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my Model :

```
public string ALTCLC { get; set; }

public string ALTGEN { get; set; }
public int ALTCNIC { get; set; }
public DateTime ALTDOB { get; set; }
[Required]

public string ALTName { get; set; }
```

Here is my Controller Name = AdultLiteracy Controller 
every thing is EF but i write my class name Upload which is not working

```
namespace LiteracyPayroll.Controllers
{
public class AdultLiteracyTeachersController : Controller
{
private PayrollDBContext db = new PayrollDBContext();

//
// GET: /AdultLiteracyTeachers/

public ActionResult Index()
{
var adulliteracyteachers = db.AdulLiteracyTeachers.Include(a => a.District);
return View(adulliteracyteachers.ToList());
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
{
foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
{
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
file.SaveAs(path);
}
ViewBag.Message = "File(s) uploaded successfully";
return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
//
// GET: /AdultLiteracyTeachers/Details/5

public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
{
AdulLiteracyTeachers adulliteracyteachers = db.AdulLiteracyTeachers.Find(id);
if (adulliteracyteachers == null)
{
return HttpNotFound();
}
return View(adulliteracyteachers);
}

/
```

Here is my View :

```
    @model LiteracyPayroll.Models.AdulLiteracyTeachers

    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    }

    <h2>Create</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
    <legend>AdulLiteracyTeachers</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DistID, "District")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("DistID", String.Empty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DistID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ALTCLC)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ALTCLC)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ALTCLC)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ALTGEN)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ALTGEN)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ALTGEN)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ALTCNIC)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ALTCNIC)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ALTCNIC)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ALTDOB)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ALTDOB)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ALTDOB)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ALTName)
    </div>


<label for="file">Upload Image:</label>
<input type="file" name="files" value="Upload Image" />
<input name="Upload" type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
</fieldset>
```

The problem I facing when i press my create button the values pass to the database but the image file is not posted
How Do I call My Upload my Action result within my existing controller class ?

Answer (score 0):

For file  posting in form, you have to make Form like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ACTION", "CONTROLLER", FormMethod.Post, new { EncType="multipart/form-data"})){
......
.....
}
```

and in action:

```
[HttpPost]

public ActionResult ACTION(AdulLiteracyTeachers model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
}
```

or you can read file from Request:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ACTION(AdulLiteracyTeachers model)
   {
       foreach (string requestFile in Request.Files)
                {
                    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[requestFile];
                    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                    }
                }
    }
```

Comment: Ehsan sajjad I have used this @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "CONTROLLER", FormMethod.Post, new { EncType="multipart/form-data"}))
but only upload function is executed other fileds are not passing to Databse

Comment: they should be posted, you are doing some other thing wrong

Comment: provide your post action as well

Comment: Dear I have added upload action now to my controller when is use (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "CONTROLLER"......   the values are not passing to database but the piture is working to save specific directiry ... only upload action is working